# Upload files from a folder in a specific sequence/order

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am making a twitter bot. At the moment, I have been able to find a way to post one image at a time (that too by specifying its name, you can see the  code). What i want this code to do is to upload image#1 then upload image#2 and so on automatically. Is it possible in python? If yes, please let me know how to do this. I don't need to sort files on the basis of extension as all files in the folder would be jpeg. The current code that I'm using is:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

def upload_media(text, filename):
    media = api.media_upload(filename)
    text = filename.split(".")[0].split("\\")[-1]
    api.update_status(text, media_ids = [media.media_id_string])
upload_media('','image#1.jpg')
```

Comment: You say 'in a specific order'. How do you determine the order?

Comment: I have saved the files in a numbered way i.e Image1, image 2, image 3.

Answer (score 0):

You want to:

- Get your files into a list. Read from a directory? Or you have a list of files somewhere in a text file? Or..? Wherever your files are listed, read from there.
- Sort your list. You said your files are named `image1`, `image2`, etc. so you can sort alphabetically.
- Use a `for` loop to loop through your files and `upload_media` one-by-one

Something like:

```
files = ['file2.jpg','file1.jpg','file3.jpg'] # or whatever
files.sort()
for file in files:
  print(file)
  upload_media(file)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Twitter-bot-from-scratch-main (1)\Twitter-bot-from-scratch-main\Twitter-Python.py", line 26, in <module>
    upload_media("HEllo", file)
NameError: name 'file' is not defined. Did you mean: 'files'?
Getting this error now

Comment: Is that `upload_media` call inside your for loop (indented underneath)? It should work... It will be difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the code that's causing the error